# Why the thread is not executing (Racket)

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a program and one func of it takes too long, say `longfunc` (the specific thing done in the longfunc is a bunch of files generated). so I want to use `thread` asynchronously  executed this `longfunc`. However, when I wrote like the following, it does not really execute `longfunc` since there are no files generated...

`(thread 
     (λ () 
       (longfunc arg1 arg2)))`

and when I get the above thread descriptor, testing whether the thread is running, it says true, this is so weird...

Can anybody explain what's going on with the thread? Is it because of some inner scheduling scheme? how to make the thread run normally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread should start and run normally. For instance, running this program

```
#lang racket

(thread (lambda ()
          (for ([i 10])
            (sleep 2)
            (printf "thread 1\n"))))


(thread (lambda ()
          (for ([i 20])
            (sleep 1)
            (printf "thread 2\n"))))
```

should show you both threads running at once.

Comment: Your answer confirmed the thread is working.... it may be other issues causing my problem..Anyway, thanks, John!

Comment: Would you mind another dumb question that: when executing the program in command line like `racket sample.rkt`, I can't see the printing out message of ""thread 1" or ""thread 2"? Is it because in thread, the output port is redirected to some otherplace? If so, I should not use `displayln` or the like to see whether the thread is executing or not?

Comment: I suspect the problem is simply that the process ends as soon as the main thread exits. Try adding a (sleep 20) to the end of the program.

Comment: You are right!!!  The main thread exits quickly(since it takes much short time) and kills the thread that is created in the main thread to execute the task that takes long time. and I tried `thread-wait` to sync as well as your suggestion :) Thanks again! It really helped!